# mysql select from two columns except duplicate values

Tags: mysql, duplicates

i have two table , Column A in table 1 and Column B in table 2

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| apple | apple |
| kiwi | x |
| banana | y |
| berry | z |

i need MySQL query to select all values from two tables expect duplicated

what I expect

| Column A |
| --- |
| kiwi |
| banana |
| berry |
| x |
| y |
| z |

All answer i see only remove duplicate, but what I want to no select duplicate at all

Thakns

Comment: If ColumnA exists in table1 and ColumnB in table2 please show them as seperate tables in your data example. Currectly the question is a little confused

Comment: If `apple` occurred in both columns in _different_ rows, should it also be excluded?

Answer (score 0):

We can use a union aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT val
FROM
(
    SELECT ColumnA AS val FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ColumnB FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY val
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

The inner union places both the A and B columns into a single column, and the outer aggregation retains only values which occur once.